# Find connected components recursively in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, networking, networkx, connected-components

Consider the following data frame:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "main": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        "component": [
            [1, 2],
            [np.nan],
            [3, 8],
            [np.nan],
            [1, 5, 6],
            [np.nan],
            [7],
            [np.nan],
            [9, 10],
            [np.nan],
            [np.nan],
        ],
    }
)
```

The column `main` represents a certain approach. Each approach consists of components. A component itself could also be an approach and is then called sub-approach.

I want to find all connected sub-approaches/components for a certain approach.

Suppose, for instance, I want to find all connected sub-approaches/components for the main approach '0'.
Then, my desired output would look like this:

```
target = pd.DataFrame({
    "main": [0, 0, 2, 2, 8, 8],
    "component": [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10]
})
```

Ideally, I want to be able to just choose the approach and then get all sub-connections.
I am convinced that there is a smart approach to do so using `networkx`. Any hint is appreciated.

Ultimately, I want to create a graph that looks somewhat like this (for approach 0):

[image]

**Additional information:**

You can explode the data frame and then remove all components from the `main` column (components are approaches that do not have any component).

```
df_exploded = df.explode(column="component").dropna(subset="component")
```

The graph can be constructed as follows:

```py
import networkx as nx
import graphviz

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(i, j) for i, j in target.values])

graph_attr = dict(rankdir="LR", nodesep="0.2")
g = graphviz.Digraph(graph_attr=graph_attr)

for k, v in G.nodes.items():
    g.node(str(k), shape="box", style="filled", height="0.35")

for n1, n2 in G.edges:
    g.edge(str(n2), str(n1))

g
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Corralien, the expected result would be the data frame called `target` in the second cell frame for approach 0. In the end, the expected result depends on the approach number I want to specify. But you can assume that the approach number equals 0 here.

Comment: Ok. I'm sorry, I misread. You can use `dfs_edges` to solve your problem. You can check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nx.dfs_edges`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_edges.html)

```
edges = df.explode(column='component').dropna(subset='component')

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='main', target='component', create_using=nx.DiGraph)

target = pd.DataFrame(nx.dfs_edges(G, 0), columns=['main', 'component'])
```

Output:

```
>>> target
   main  component
0     0          1
1     0          2
2     2          3
3     2          8
4     8          9
5     8         10
```

To extract the subgraph, use:

```
H = G.edge_subgraph(nx.dfs_edges(G, 0))
```